# Limit a scrollbar's OnValueChanged to full step intervals only

Tags: unity, c#, gui

So I have done some research on the matter but I can't find anything.

I created a UI scrollbar and asigned 10 steps to it.Then I noticed that the values of the scrollbar does not change in reference of the handle's steps but in reference of the pointer's position(like a slider).That seriously slows down the performance since it has a lot more to process "onValueChanged" and it is unnecessary for what I am trying to achieve.

The values of the steps should go step 1: 0.1(1),step 2: 0.2(2) etc.I need to get these values and nothing in between or the step that the handle is currently on.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed the value, when the scrollbar is dragged, changes in accordance to pointer's position (this does not happen if you are using keys). From [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Scrollbar.html):

> The Scrollbar has a single event called On Value Changed that responds
>   as the user drags the handle.

Scrollbar `OnValueChanged` is called at most once per frame. This allows you to react to scrollbar movement in every frame.

If you need to fix your update operations to a given step you need to account for that in your code. Store the last scrollbar `Value`, and in `OnValueChanged` check if the new position corresponds to a different step than in the previous frame, otherwise return (this will have little impact on performance). Example code (incomplete):

```
public OnValueChanged(float value) {
  currentStep = Mathf.round(scrollbar.Value * 10.0f);
  if (currentStep == lastStep) return;

  // Your code here (depending on your needs you may need to iterate
  // from last to current step)...

  lastStep = currentStep;
}
```

One thing that is calling my attention is that a scrollbar will automatically set its handle `size` according to the target scroll area, thus making the `numberOfSteps` unuseful. Perhaps you shall consider using a `Slider` instead.